# Trying to update data to database in WordPress by php code snippets , why the data is not updating in database and showing 404 error?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, wordpress

Trying to update data in mysql database(not local server). Using basic PHP and  jQuery  but the data is not updating and showing 404 error status in inspect section . what is the problem in my code  ?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        // Handle update button click
        $(".update-btn").on("click", function () {
            var id = $(this).data("id");
            var name = $("td[data-id='" + id + "'][data-field='name']").text();
            var description = $("td[data-id='" + id + "'][data-field='description']").text();

            // Send AJAX request to update data (custom post content)
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: window.location.href,
                data: {
                    action: "update",
                    id: id,
                    name: name,
                    description: description
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    // Handle success, if needed
                }
            });
        });
```

```
elseif ($action === 'update') {
    $id = intval($_POST['id']);
    $name = sanitize_text_field($_POST['name']);
    $description = sanitize_text_field($_POST['description']);

    $wpdb->update(
        $table_name,
        array(
            'name' => $name,
            'description' => $description,
        ),
        array('id' => $id)
    );
```